# Prevent data duplication over multiple indices in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Data duplication prevention is handled at the index level with the field "_id".
However, to avoid having huge indices, I work with several small indices linked under an alias. Is there a mechanism in place to check existing _ids at the alias level (over multiple indices) when a document is inserted or should it be handled at the application level ?

[indices architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQU3R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not natively, no. you'd need to handle this in your own code

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting your document, you need to first find out which real index contains your document via the alias using

```
GET alias/_search?q=_id:123456&filter_path=hits.hits._index
```

In the response you'll get the concrete index name that you can then use to index/update your new document version.

Comment: I'm afraid that making this check for every document inserted is not option for my use case (that would considerably slow down the data ingestion process)

Comment: Another way to deal with this is to hash the id and based on the hash decide in which index the document would land, that way you'd always know in which index to look for a given id

Comment: Yes I think this is the way to go. But is there a built-in way to do this with elastic, (like an alias that could conditionnally insert documents in an index or another) ? Or is it the application that inserts the data that will have to implement that routing logic ?

Comment: ES doesn't provide that at the index-level (only at the shard level with the routing parameter). But it's a one-liner in your application logic.